# Meta silliness: reviews

Tags: discussion, meta

I just noticed that I (among four others) was the **"top reviewer of all time"** on cs.meta, with one review (which I don't even recall making). Does this seem as pointless to you as it does to me? Do we really need a review queue here? Do we really need a review queue on *any* meta site? Should I be asking this on SE.meta? Should I even care?

Comment: it is probably more difficult to turn this feature off, than let it be..

Comment: answer: no, you shouldnt care

Comment: Heh. Any chance that ether of you would turn these into answers so that I could go back to the queue and recommend deletion? I need to stay on top of the all-time reviewers list.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta.meta.cs.SE?

Comment: @Raphael the meta site for meta is meta, with [meta-tag:meta] as the applicable tag

Answer (score 3):

Meta sites just use the SE software (with some modifications), for better or worse. So it figures there'd be a review queue. I agree that they could be turned off here.

They are probably necessary on sites with more Meta volume, though. [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), for instance, has more traffic than our main site.

Answer (score 3):

Meta has question closure and tag wikis like anywhere else. Why would we turn the queues off here?